# Error while adding listener-class

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc, web

why when I added in web.xml file

```
 <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

I see error

```
2015-11-07 12:27:33,086] Artifact Choouse:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
07-Nov-2015 12:27:38.208 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory D:\english\apache-tomcat-8.0.23-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-8.0.23\webapps\manager
07-Nov-2015 12:27:38.293 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory D:\english\apache-tomcat-8.0.23-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-8.0.23\webapps\manager has finished in 84 ms
```

Comment: **See server log for details.**

Comment: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file

Comment: **Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file**

Comment: Ali - you seem to have difficulty in understanding a couple of basic troubleshooting techniques.  1) >>Read<< the error messages.  2)  >>Look<< in the log files.  (And >>read<< what they say.)

Comment: at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.warning(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:99)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:433)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:347)

Comment: at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(XSDHandler.java:4166)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)

Comment: at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1906)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:746)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:379)
 at

Comment: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3138)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:880)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
 at

Comment: No ... I didn't say cut and paste them as comments.  I said >> **READ** << them.

Comment: at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
 at

Comment: at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:347)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429)

Comment: 07-Nov-2015 12:27:32.919 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
07-Nov-2015 12:27:32.921 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors

Comment: @AliHolmatov, the logs you posted are completely unreadable.
Please, edit your question adding the error logs; remember to format them as code, otherwise they are unreadable and some parts could be trimmed out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is that there is a syntax error in (probably) your "web.xml" file.  Somewhere in the log messages it will probably tell you what file the syntax error is in and the line number and character number.  Check the file carefully, and compare it with the DTD / schema / documentation for the XML file.

Hint: in all the examples I have seen, a `<listener>` element contains a `<listener-class>` element.